# Running multiple rules listeners in Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am trying to use the Twitter4j API to track twitts according to some rule criteria.
The API works fine when there is one rule, but when I am adding two or three rules I am getting this error:

```
420:Returned by the Search and Trends API when you are being rate limited     (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting).
Returned by the Streaming API:
Too many login attempts in a short period of time.
Running too many copies of the same application authenticating with the same account name.
Exceeded connection limit for user
```

The code I'm using is:

```
// create the TwitterStream object

ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

cb.setDebugEnabled(false).setOAuthConsumerKey(accountdetails.ConsumerKey)
                .setOAuthConsumerSecret(accountdetails.ConsumerSecret)
                .setOAuthAccessToken(accountdetails.AccessToken)
                .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(accountdetails.AccessTokenSecret)

Configuration config = cb.build();

TwitterStream twitterStream = new 
TwitterStreamFactory(config).getInstance();

// create the filter

FilterQuery filter = new FilterQuery();
filter.track(trackList);

// create the Listener object

// Twitter4jListener is a class that implements the StatusListener interface
Twitter4jListener listener = new Twitter4jListener(rule);
twitterStream.addListener(listener);
twitterStream.filter(filter);
```

Do I use the API incorrectly? or the API generally have a limit on a number of Listeners that can work in parallel?

Comment: can you show a snipet on how you are doing with multiple listeners? Maybe you're not reusing the connection and each listener creates a separate connection

Comment: on every rule added I am running the code above.
what in the code needs to be reused when I want to add new rule criteria?

Comment: yeah, you will need to reuse the TwitterStream when running the same code. with your current code you are doing a new instance of TwitterStreamFactory. Try creating a single TwitterStream instance and run the other stuff in parallel